Advice on approach to powering journeys in SFMC
Full disclosure, I am a Marketer who has mainly been working with SFMC but now have our data in Salesforce and are looking at creating a number of journeys in SFMC based on the SF data. I have written my fair share of automations in SQL and used AMPscript but I am by no means a SF Admin.
That said, we're looking to create a number of journeys based off of a date fields. We have "arrival_date" and "departure_date" fields and want to power a number of journeys at different times before the arrival date (example 3, 7, 14, or 30 days before arrival).
For the first journey, we just wrote an automation to run nightly and grab the records that were 3 days out and the automation completing was the trigger for the journey.
My thought is that it would be easier if we created a field in SF called "Days To Arrival" and had a script of some sort run on a schedule and update the data in that field which would just be a formula subtracting the arrival date from the current date.  That way, once the field is updated and matches the criteria for the journey, the record would enter.  I should mention that we work with around 100-150,000 active records.
Does that make sense and/or how hard would it be to do in SF or should I just keep to my automation method?
Appreciate any thoughts on this!
Regards,
Matt

I think I answered my own question. I just created the Days To Arrival field and did it as a formula using the arrival date. I think I'm good to go now!
